# Multiple DB Schema & migrations with Doctrine2 & PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, schema

I have a PG database containing multiple schemas.

I have a symfony2 application which need to connect to only one of them.

If I don't configure anything, by default Doctrine2 searches in all the schemas so it try to make `SELECT` on table where it haven't the right.

I followed this answer : [symfony2 + doctrine2@postgresql setting a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654651/symfony2-doctrine2postgresql-setting-a-schema)

Now it seems to go only in the shema I specified but it is still looking for some tables no present in my schema but in other ones.

When I execute something ldoctrine:migrations:diff

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                     
  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "pgstatspacknameid"':  
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "pgstatspacknameid" does not exist           
  LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "pgstatspacknameid"                                   
                                              ^                                                     

  [PDOException]                                                                           
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "pgstatspacknameid" does not exist  
  LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "pgstatspacknameid"                          
                                              ^
```

So following the doctrine migration documentation, I added this line in the connection configuration :

```
        schema_filter: ~^(?!pgstats)~
```

It still always try to make `SELECT` in those tables...

Answer (score 0):

You need the option --db-configuration to the migrate command. 
It takes a configuration file as argument. 
Try with the following content of the configuration file.

```
<?php
return array(
    "driverClass"=>"AppBundle\Driver",
    "host" => "localhost",
    "user" => "test",
    "password" => "test",
    "dbname" => "test"
        );
?>
```

Furthermore I changed vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/SchemaPostgreSqlSchemaManager.php to always prepend the schema to the sequence names.

like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function _getPortableSequencesList($sequences)
{
    $sequenceDefinitions = array();
    foreach ($sequences as $sequence) {//+ || true
        if ($sequence['schemaname'] != 'public' || true) {
            $sequenceName = $sequence['schemaname'] . "." . $sequence['relname'];
        } else {
            $sequenceName = $sequence['relname'];
        }

        $sequenceDefinitions[$sequenceName] = $sequence;
    }
    $list = array();

    foreach ($this->filterAssetNames(array_keys($sequenceDefinitions)) as $sequenceName) {
        $list[] = $this->_getPortableSequenceDefinition($sequenceDefinitions[$sequenceName]);
    }
    return $list;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getPortableNamespaceDefinition(array $namespace)
{
    return $namespace['nspname'];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function _getPortableSequenceDefinition($sequence)
{//+ || true
    if ($sequence['schemaname'] != 'public' || true) {
        $sequenceName = $sequence['schemaname'] . "." . $sequence['relname'];
    } else {
        $sequenceName = $sequence['relname'];
    }

    $data = $this->_conn->fetchAll('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM ' . $this->_platform->quoteIdentifier($sequenceName));

    return new Sequence($sequenceName, $data[0]['increment_by'], $data[0]['min_value']);
}
```

(added the or true both places where assumed that schema name != 'public')

Comment: Thanks i am going to test this solution !
Do you have an idea of how override this class without change the file in vendor ?

Comment: Not tested but you might be able to override getSchemaManager from AbstractPostgresqlDriver to return a custom SchemaManager with the above changes.